# Is there a 'conjugation' on every algebraically closed field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Then the polynomial $x^2+1\in K[x]$ has two distinct roots (when $K$ doesn't have characteristic 2). Let's suggestively call them $i$ and $-i$.

> Does there exist an automorphism $\phi$ of $K$ such that $\phi(i)=-i$?

This is something I've been wondering about for a while. I'm asking this question here because I, unfortunately, have very little background in field theory and have no clue on how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The second statement is false; if $K$ has characteristic $2$ we have $x^2 + 1 = (x + 1)^2$, so the polynomial has only a single root, namely $1 = -1$.

Comment: If $K$ has characteristic $2$, then the two roots of $x^2+1$ are not distinct (namely, $1$ is a double root).

Comment: Oh, characteristic two. The algebraist's "you need to assume the limit exists".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example, in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_5$, the two roots of $x^2+1$ are $1+1$ and $1+1+1$, and there's obviously no automorphism that interchanges them.

Comment: Very nicely formulated!

Answer (score 6):

Henning's answer is correct.  However, if we let $F$ be the smallest subfield of $K$ and $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ is **irreducible** in $F$, then your automorphism is legitimate.  Here's why:

Let $L \subset K$ be its splitting field. Since $L$ is a splitting field of $f$, then it is by definition a Galois extension. At this point, we can consider the automorphism group $Aut(L/F)$.  An element $\phi \in Aut(L/F)$ is a $F$-automorphism.  That is to say, it is an automorphism of $L$ (that can be extended to $K$) that fixes $F$.

Next, it is a theorem that, since $L$ is a Galois extension $[L:F] = |Aut(L/F)|$.  It is also a theorem that the elements of $Aut(L/F)$ are uniquely determined by their actions, as permutations, on the roots of the polynomial.

Obviously, the identity automorphism will fix the roots of $f$.  Since $f$ is irreducible in $F$, then $[L:F] > 1$, and so there must exist at least one nontrivial automorphism.  Since there are only two roots that *can* be permuted, then that nontrivial automorphism *must* swap the roots of $f$.

Comment: I don't follow. I see that you've defined an automorphism of $L$. Are you claiming that it extends to an automorphism of $K$? I believe this if $K$ is algebraic over $L$ but it's not immediately obvious to me in the general case.

Comment: Your objection has been addressed here, though I'm still not entirely satisfied: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219869/extension-of-automorphism-of-field-to-algebraically-closed-field

Comment: Also, this argument is overkill; you don't need to appeal to so much Galois theory. You can just directly verify that $\sigma(i) = -i$ is an automorphism of $L$; the only thing you need is that $L$ has basis $\{ 1, i \}$ as a $K$-vector space.

Comment: Ah, yes.  That is easier!  I really appreciate your comments on my posts @QiaochuYuan.  I've learned a good bit from them now and in the past.

Comment: While it was shown at mentioned other question that every automorphism of a subfield extends to an automorphism of the algebraically closed field, that extended automorphism may have infinite order while the original automorphism has finite order. I would hesitate  to call an automorphism a "conjugation" if it does not have order$~2$. For instance over $\Bbb F_3$ the polynomial $x^2+1$ is irrededucible, and there is a (Frobenius) automorphism of order$~2$ of $\Bbb F_9$ that interchanges its roots, but the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_3$ does not have any automorphism of order$~2$.