# Why is $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong G_{\mathbb{Q}}/{\{\sigma \in G_{\mathbb{Q}}: \ \sigma|_K=id_K \}}$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

[Here](http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/users/pappa/missions/doc/Ohrid_extended_abstr_pappalardi.pdf), in page $1$, the absolute Galois group is defined by $$G_{\mathbb{Q}}:=\text{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})=\{\sigma: \bar{\mathbb{Q} }\to \bar{\mathbb{Q}}, \ \text{field automorphism} \}$$ is a profinite group. Then the article defines for any Galois extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, the Galois group by $$\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong G_{\mathbb{Q}}/{\{\sigma \in G_{\mathbb{Q}}: \ \sigma|_K=id_K \}}$$ to be the quotient group.

**My question-** Why is $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong G_{\mathbb{Q}}/{\{\sigma \in G_{\mathbb{Q}}: \ \sigma|_K=id_K \}}$ ?

Because we know by definition of Galois extension  $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) = \{\sigma \in \text{Aut}(K): \ \sigma(a)=a, \ \forall a \in \mathbb{Q} \}$.

**So the question-**

How to see the relation  $ \{\sigma \in \text{Aut}(K): \ \sigma(a)=a, \ \forall a \in \mathbb{Q} \} \cong G_{\mathbb{Q}}/{\{\sigma \in G_{\mathbb{Q}}: \ \sigma|_K=id_K \}}$ ?

How to see the isomorphism ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a map
$$
G_\mathbb{Q} \to \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})
$$
given by restriction. It is plain that the kernel of this map is
$$
\{ \sigma \in G_\mathbb{Q} : \sigma|_K = \text{id}_K\},
$$
and so you need to know that this map is surjective, i.e. that every automorphism of $K$ lifts to an automorphism of the algebraic closure. This is one of the more difficult lemmas of Galois theory; see a proof here for instance: [Extension of field automorphism to automorphism of algebraic closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370880/extension-of-field-automorphism-to-automorphism-of-algebraic-closure)

Comment: Thanks for help

Comment: Sorry, I have one question. Is $ \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})=\{\sigma \in \text{Aut}(K): \ \sigma(a)=a \ \forall a \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ in the map  $G_\mathbb{Q} \to \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ ? Or you are meaning by  $ \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$, the quotient one, defined in the note?   Because,I can't see how the kernel of the map is $\{ \sigma \in G_\mathbb{Q} : \sigma|_K = \text{id}_K\}$.

Comment: @mathvision I mean the former. (Which is isomorphic to the latter, so whatever). Our map from $G_\mathbb{Q}$ to $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ just restricts an automorphism to $K$, so it is tautological that the kernel of this map is the set of automorphisms that restrict to the identity morphism of $K$. (That's just the definition of a kernel.)

Comment: ok,thank you very much