# There exists an automorphism of algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ that fixed $i$ and does not fix $2^{1/3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

There exists an automorphism of algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ that fixed $i$ and does not fix $2^{1/3}$.

I propose to use $x^2-2^{2/3}$ and see that $-2^{1/3}$ is another root (conjugate), so when swapping the root, $i$ is fixed.

Is my argument correct？

Comment: What do you mean by "closure of $\Bbb{Q}$"? The algebraic closure?

Comment: Why is $i$ fixed in your proposal?

Comment: Hint: _The Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory_ is a fundamental theorem in the theory of field automorphisms.

Comment: Doesn't $2^{\frac{1}{3}}=2.2^{-\frac{2}{3}}\in \mathbb{Q}[2^{\frac{2}{3}}]$?

Comment: We need to work with $K = \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{2})$ which is splitting field of $(x^{2} + 1)(x^{3} - 2)$. If Galois group $G = \textrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ then we can find the subgroup $H$ of $G$ as set of those automorphisms of $K$ which fix $E = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ so that fixed field of $H$ is $E$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^3 - 2$ over ${\mathbb Q}(i)$. The extension $K : {\mathbb Q}(i)$ is Galois and because $x^ 3 - 2$ is irreducible over ${\mathbb Q}(i)$, the Galois group $\text{Gal}(K : {\mathbb Q}(i))$ acts transitively on the roots of $x^3 - 2$. So, pick any element of that Galois group that sends $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{2}$. Note, by the way, that every element of that Galois group fixes $i$.

Finally, extend this automorphism of $K$ to an automorphism of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ (see [extension of automorphism of field to algebraically closed field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219869/extension-of-automorphism-of-field-to-algebraically-closed-field) or [extension of automorphism of field to algebraically closed field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219869/extension-of-automorphism-of-field-to-algebraically-closed-field)).